# `elif` statement failing to a check string for a substring

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, substring

**Very short version:** my `elif` statement that is supposed to check if a substring is present, is saying that a substring isn't present when it is.

**Longer version:** I'm breaking down a list to extract useful information. As the list is derived from a user I want to check it's been filled out correctly before I proceed. However, when I try to run some basic checks (e.g. are the correct strings present) it returns a message telling me the list items do not meet the specification I require.

I have checked and my example data is actually filled-in correctly. However, I'm struggling to work out why my check fails.

An example that replicates my problem is given below:

```
    #Example of a string I am turning into a list
meta_thingys_str = "TagExampleA(omit if: Data Example 1), TagExampleA(include if: Data Example 2), TagExampleB(include if: any), TagExampleC(include if: any), TagExampleC(omit if: Data Example 3)"

#Split the string based on ', ' into a list
meta_thingys = meta_thingys_str.split(", ")

#Useful for later, to see if the list items are laid out in a manner my code can read.
obligatory_characters = (' if: ' and ')' and '(') 


#Let's loop through our "thingys"
for thingy in meta_thingys:

    #A silly example - I have a lot more if-statements in my actual code but
    #Obviously `elif` won't run without an `if` statement.
    if ("include" in thingy) and ("any" not in thingy):
        print('yay')

    #This checks to see if the layout and characters of the list items are 
    #roughly correct
    elif (obligatory_characters not in thingy):
        print("'" + thingy + "' not recognised as a valid input (Type A Error)\n")

    #This is *supposed to* check whether either the key word 'omit' or 'include'
    #is present within each list item. Seemingly, it fails.
    elif ('omit' not in thingy) or ('include' not in thingy):
        print("\n'" + thingy + "' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)\n")
```

This returns the following error...

```
'TagExampleA(omit if: Data Example 1)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)

yay

'TagExampleB(include if: any)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)


'TagExampleC(include if: any)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)


'TagExampleC(omit if: Data Example 3)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)
```

I also tried a small change, where I set as a variable the condition for the elif statement:

```
#Useful for later, to see if the list (derived from a user input) contains the
#proper information
obligatory_characters = (' if: ' and ')' and '(')
#!>>> note the change here <<<!
variable_characters = ('omit' or 'include')

#Let's loop through our "thingys"
for thingy in meta_thingys:
#A silly example I have a lot more if-statements in my actual code
if ("include" in thingy) and ("any" not in thingy):
    print('yay')

#This checks to see if the layout and characters of the list items are
#roughly correct
elif (obligatory_characters not in thingy):
    print("'" + thingy + "' not recognised as a valid input (Type A Error)\n")

#This is *supposed to* check whether either the key word 'omit' or 'include'
#is present within each list item. Seemingly, it fails.
#!>>> and corresponding change here <<<!
elif (variable_characters not in thingy):
    print("\n'" + thingy + "' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)\n")
```

This however just gives a slightly different message...

```
yay

'TagExampleB(include if: any)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)


'TagExampleC(include if: any)' not recognised as a valid input (Type B Error)
```

Comment: @superbrain well you can just run the code and no one is forcing you to read the long version. In the past I've left out information and people have responded with alternative solutions that don't actually help. Trying to find a balance is all.

Comment: @superbrain case and point, I thought my first `elif` statement was fine and functional which is why I included it, as it had me confused. As it transpires it was not fine.

Comment: I could trim a single line of actual code if I had to, two if you include a comment. I'm sorry if this bothers you. However, you are incorrect; I misunderstood the behaviour of my statements quite significantly.  If you're not going to look into things you probably can't help.

Comment: @superbrain honestly it didn't even occur to me that that might be the issue. In fact `obligatory_characters = (' if: ' and ')' and '(')` seemed to make things better after I introduced it so I thought I had made headway with that particular experiment. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got statements that aren't doing what you think they're doing.

```
elif ('omit' not in thingy) or ('include' not in thingy):
```

The only way this isn't true is if both `omit` and `include` are in `thingy`, which isn't true in any of your cases.

Other things that don't mean what you think they mean:

```
obligatory_characters = (' if: ' and ')' and '(')
print(obligatory_characters)
# '('
```

If you want to check that several different strings exist in a string, you need to do something like

```
must_exist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for to_match in must_exist:
    if to_match not in search_string:
        return False
return True
```